# Why $r_p$ and $r_s$ are maximized at the Brewster angle?

Tags: optics

Ellipsometry measures the ratio of the amplitude reflection coefficients $r_p/r_s$. Ellipsometry measurement is generally performed at the Brewster angle. Why are $r_p$ and $r_s$ maximized at the Brewster angle?

Comment: rp *and* rs are not maximised at the Brewster angle...?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. p-polarised light is not reflected if the incidence angle is the Brewster angle. The reasons for this are due to the boundary conditions for Maxwell's equations. There are a number of SE questions about this, or you could look up the "Fresnel equations" on Wikipedia.

Thus at the Brewster angle $r_p =0$ and $r_s \neq 0$.

The idea of doing ellipsometry at angles close to the Brewster angle is to maximise the *difference* in $r_p$ and $r_s$.